# How to load DICOM pixel data in browser preserving HU values?

Tags: png, jpeg, dicom, bmp

I need to display the DICOM images in a browser. This requires, the DICOM to be converted to PNG (or any other compatible) format.

I also need to calculate some overlay pixels based on dynamic input from the user. On conversion to PNG, I am getting 4 values (Alpha, R, G, B). But I can not use these values for my calculations. I need the original HU values from the DICOM images.

Is there any way that, PNG can contain the original DICOM values. I heard that using monochromatic 16 bit PNG format it is possible. How do we do that?

Alternatively, how to load DICOM pixel data in browser preserving HU values?

Answer (score 1):

When you convert DICOM pixel data to other non-DICOM format like PNG, BMP, JPG, J2K etc., the data you are looking for is lost. You may further research for TIF format whether it preserves the data and it loads in browser. I guess it will not.

I will recommend to avoid this way. Instead, I will suggest using DICOM pixel data as-is in browser. This can be achieved by involving some java-script DICOM toolkit for browsers like [cornerstone](https://github.com/cornerstonejs/cornerstone). You may also look for other toolkit if available and suits you.

Note that this involves learning curve. It will be too broad here to explain its working.